# Wordpress Divi contact form (Make sure all required fields are filled in)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have been transfering website to another domain,and now i am having an issue on a new site,where contact form will not validate even though form is filled out.

I have researched about this problem,and had to change input fields id inside the contact for input fields,as they had special characters.I am still having the same issue though
"Make sure you fill in all required fields"
I was thinking it has something to do with my other error: 
where jQuery.def is not defined

**UPDATE**
I have managed to fix the problem by providing a proper version of JQuery.There used to be some sort of conflict depending on what version I used.1.12.4 - did the trick for me.

Comment: There are no special characters.

Comment: When initially I created a form in theme editor i set id as "First Name","Last Name".Space was considered a special character so it didn't work

Comment: I suggest to think about that a bit different: "First Name" is just an invalid ID.  This is b/c in HTML an id can not contain a space. The space is not special in an id, it is just not available. But that is only by the book, browsers normally have no problems with that and accept id's containing spaces even being a single space. I can't suggest breaking the rules here, but in practice this is less an issue. It's just not standard conform so one could not expect it to work with a standard conform client.

Comment: this is official fix from theme creators.It worked on original website,but once i moved it-it doesn't work